# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. (even after driver reinstall )

Tags: ubuntu, driver, nvidia

i had faced with an issue on nvidia driver for 2080Ti (need to install nvidia driver + CUDA for torch usage).

```
me@server:~$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 20 2019, 17:12:48)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

i think that issue is caused by the next problem:

```
me@server:~$ sudo nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver.
Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

of course, i had googled a lot on this issue and tried all found solutions: i had re-install all drivers from scratch, tried different versions of the drivers (385, 410, 415, 430, 435). unfortunately, all these steps didn't help.

i need something fresh solution on it :)

P.S. of course, re-install Ubuntu will work, but right now i have no time to do it because i need to run torch :(

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and SuperUser cover more general questions that include hardware.

Comment: totally agree, can i remove/delete this question?

Comment: I think you should be able to remove this question then post it there.